# CView as tab on CMFCTabCtrl, does not draw invalidated area (on dragging)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I have a `CWinAppEx` MDI application, VS2017. The `ChiledFrame` is covered with (I altered the names for this question) `CMyView`:

```
pDocTemplate = new CMultiDocTemplate(   IDR_MYTYPE,
                                        RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyDoc),
                                        RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyChildFrame),
                                        RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyView));
```

`CMyView` client-rect is covered with a `CMFCTabCtrl` (`m_wndTabs`): It has 2 tabs, objects of `CViewTest1` and `CViewTest2` classes (derived from MFC `CView`). This is the relevant part of `MyView::Create` function:

```
    CRect rectDummy;
    rectDummy.SetRectEmpty();

    // Create tabs window:
    if (!m_wndTabs.Create(CMFCTabCtrl::STYLE_3D_ONENOTE, rectDummy, this, 1))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create output tab window\n");
        return -1;      // fail to create
    }

    // Create output panes ('300' value is dummy client-rect is updated on CViewTest1/2::OnSize):

    CViewTest1 *pWnd1 = (CViewTest1*)RUNTIME_CLASS(CViewTest1)->CreateObject();
    pWnd1->Create(nullptr, nullptr, LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(0, 0, 300, 300), this, 1, pContext);
    pWnd1->SetFont(&afxGlobalData.fontRegular);

    CViewTest2 *pWnd2 = (CViewTest2*)RUNTIME_CLASS(CViewTest2)->CreateObject();
    pWnd2->Create(nullptr, nullptr, LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(0, 0, 300, 300), this, 2, pContext);
    pWnd2->SetFont(&afxGlobalData.fontRegular);

    m_wndTabs.AddTab(pWnd1, L"Tab 1");
    m_wndTabs.AddTab(pWnd2, L"Tab 2");

    // Redraw tab 0 ("Tab 1"): <--- Here already smells an issue.
    m_wndTabs.SetActiveTab(1); // (This need to move to 1 & back to 0)
    m_wndTabs.SetActiveTab(0);
```

The `parent` of `CViewTest1` and `CViewTest2` objects is `CMyView` object.
m_wndTabs resized to cover the whole client area at:

```
void CMyView::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    CView::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

    if (m_wndTabs) // Tab control should cover the whole client area:
        m_wndTabs.SetWindowPos(nullptr, -1, -1, cx, cy, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOZORDER);

}
```

Now, when I drag one child-frame over another, and back: The control-tab behaves as expected, but CViewTest1 object (on active tab) does not get OnDraw(). It looks like that:

[image]

**Any idea?**

Comment: *"Any idea?"* - Yes. Something is wrong. Show a [mcve] to get help.

Comment: Are CViewTest1 and 2 CView classes? If so. a CView should not contain other views. The outer frame should contain the Tab with the Views.

Comment: @xMRi You are right. On the `Create` calls, instead of: `this`, I changed to: `this->GetParent()` and it solved the problem.

Comment: I formed an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CViewTest1 and 2 are CView classes.

A CView should not contain other views.

The outer frame should contain the Tab with the views.

Comment: It will be helpful to add `CMFCTabCtrl` and `CView` tags to the topic. These tags do not exist, and I can't create new ones yet.

Comment: I don't think that this new Tag is usefull. The class name can be easily found in the normal search. Tag this as an answer if it was the answer for you.